# algorithm to find optimal combination

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

I have an algorithm modeling problem I could use some help in. Consider this:
A person has pre-purchased tickets of

- 0 to 5 km x 4
- 6 to 10 km x 2
- 11 to 15 km x 8

lets call these different types A, B, C respectively for ease of understanding such that, this person has a count of:

- 4 A's
- 2 B's
- and 8 C's

The person wants to travel 18km today and can use any combination of the pre purchased tickets they have in order to pay for their travel. For example they could use two of their eight C's which are equivalent to a max of 30 km travel or they can use four of their four A's which is equivalent to a max of 20 km of travel.

I figured for my algorithm to efficiently select the best combination of pre-purchased tickets it ought to:

1. minimize the distance between the sum of the pre-purchased ticket
   distance and the actual distance being travelled on the present
   date.
2. minimize the number of pre-purchased tickets used to cover
   the actual distance travelled.

What I've tried is this:
Using the example above, where A, B, and C are ranges (0 to 5),(6 to 10),(11 to 15) in kms respectively;
Person has:
1. 4 A's 
2. 2 B's 
3. and 8 C's

let x be today's travel distance. x = 18 km

- step 1: look for a range in which x is bounded inclusively.
- step 1.2: if such a range exists then select that range.
- step 1.3: decrement the count for that type of pre-purchased ticket by one.
- step 1.4: terminate the algorithm.
- step 2: if such a range does not exist, look for the largest range available.
- step 3: decrement x by the ceiling of that range. example x - c(max) = 18 - 15.
- step 4: decrement the count for that type of pre-purchased ticket by one. 7 C's remain.
- step 5: re-evaluate x. example x = x - c(max) = 3.
- step 6: goto step one.

Though my answer provides a solution, I'm not sure if this is optimized. I'd prefer a O(nlogn) complexity.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: First you need to somehow define the relationship between the goal of minimising waste and minimising the number of tickets, as the two contradict each other.

Comment: Furthermore I wouldn't bother with ranges, simply divide every number by 5 (be careful with rounding), and you'll end up with tickets for 1,2 or 3 "units". A journey of 18km will be 4 units long, a 30km journey will be 6 units long and so on. It won't make the algorithm noticeably faster but it makes the implementation a lot cleaner.

Comment: @biziclop Thanks! please put this in an answer so I can accept. Using units instead of ranges makes my life soooooo much easier, hadn't realized. I'll just convert every pre-purchased ticket into units and store the sum of the units, then simply deduct appropriate number of units for the present distance. perfect and elegant.

Comment: This is similar to the **[change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)**. For the ticket ranges in the question, the [greedy version of the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem#Greedy_method) will work.